# How to retain month/year from the day/month/year date format using R

Tags: r, date, format

There is an excel file containing dates in the form day/month/year. I want to retain the month and the year in the form month/year using R.

I have tried by making use of the function "format" as below:

```
date = c("2/8/2018","22/11/2018","1/2/2019")
n.date <- format(as.Date(date), "%m/%Y")
```

It gives:

```
n.date
[1] "08/0002" "11/0022" "02/0001"
```

However, I expect to have something like

```
"8/2018" "11/2018" "2/2019".
```

Please, how do I go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `format` option in your call to `as.Date`, when you parse the strings into dates, with the mask `%d/%m/%Y`.  Then, call `format()` with the month-year mask you want:

```
date = c("2/8/2018", "22/11/2018", "1/2/2019")
n.date <- as.Date(date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

format(n.date, "%m/%Y")

[1] "08/2018" "11/2018" "02/2019"
```

To remove the leading zeroes:

```
output <- format(n.date, "%m/%Y")
output <- sub("^0*", "", output)
output

[1] "8/2018"  "11/2018" "2/2019"
```

Comment: thanks! @Tim Biegeleisen. Is there a way to get rid of the zeros preceding 8 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you check `as.Date(date)` it doesn't give you correct dates. So usually the answer by @Tim is the way to go however, you can also use regex to achieve your desired result here

```
sub("\\d+/", "", date)
#[1] "8/2018"  "11/2018" "2/2019"
```

This deletes a number followed by "/" in `date`.